# Keras: weighted average of embedding layers

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am currently implementing a sequence model in Keras and want to utilize two (or more) pre-trained word embeddings. Currently, my way to go is to average both embedding matrices before passing it to Keras. However, I want to do weighted averaging instead.

Of course I can optimize the weights as a form of hyperparameter, but am wondering for a way to do it as part of the model, e.g., through a softmax dense layer for weighting. Ideally, I would have two options, the first fits the weights for merging the whole matrices, and the second has weights on a word level for merging the vectors. I have not figured out yet how to do it properly though and would be happy for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

For averaging, you need that both embeddings have the same output size.

You can simply stack them in the last dimension and pass them to a Dense layer:

```
inputs = Input((length,))

embedding1 = getEmbeddingFor(inputs)
embedding2 = getEmbeddingFor2(inputs)

#stacks into shape (batch, length, embedding_size, 2)
stacked = Lambda(lambda x: K.stack([x[0],x[1]], axis=-1))([embedding1,embedding2])

#weights to (batch, length, embedding_size, 1)
weighted = Dense(1, use_bias=False)(stacked)

#removes the last dimension
weighted = Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(x, axis=-1))(weighted)
```

---

Or, if you don't mind having a lot of weights instead of simply two weights, and if the sizes are different, and if you want a lot more intelligence in the weighting, you can do a very simple concatenation:

```
weighted = Concatenate()([embedding1, embedding2])   
weighted = Dense(similarToSize)(weighted)
```

The second approach might not sound like weighting, but if you think of it for a while, two embeddings might not have the same meanings for the same positions, and averaging two values of different nature might not result in great things. (But, of course, neural networks are obscure and only testing can prove this statement)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Weirdly though the code is much slower, twice as long for each epoch. Any idea why? There should be just two weights more to learn, right?

Comment: I can't imagine why... Keras has some strange behaviors sometimes. I've seen huge models using Resnets with attachments work well while smaller models fill up the GPU memory. I don't know what's going on behind the curtains.

Comment: I have the impression that running one batch on the GPU takes roughly the same time no matter its size. But models big enough seem to use the GPU in two steps for a single batch. (This is just a very superficial suspicion)

Comment: concerning speed -- it could be that dimension removal takes time... I suppose